# Django class based views form submit 405 method not allowed

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to make a email submit form in a django app.  Coming from Flask though, I'm a bit confused as I'm trying to do this with class based views, but am pretty stuck.

I'm currently getting this error but unsure how to make it successfully post

```
Method Not Allowed (POST): /newsletter/
Method Not Allowed: /newsletter/
```

My models class has this

```
class Newsletter(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
```

My forms.py has this

```
from django import forms

class NewsletterForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=200)

    def send_email(self):
        # send email using the self.cleaned_data dictionary
        pass
```

my urls file has this

```
path('newsletter/', views.NewsletterView.as_view(), name='newsletter'),
```

and my form submit in my html is like this

```
        <form action="/newsletter/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            <label for="email">Email: </label>
            <input id="email" type="email" name="email_field" placeholder="email@example.com">
            <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
        </form>
```

And here is the views function

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Post
from blog.forms import NewsletterForm

class PostList(generic.ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-created_on')
    template_name = 'index.html'
    paginate_by = 3

class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'

class NewsletterView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = "newsletter.html"
    form_class = NewsletterForm
    success_url = '/thanks/'
    def form_valid(self, form):
        # This method is called when valid form data has been POSTed.
        # It should return an HttpResponse.
        form.send_email()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Can you add your view?

Comment: It looks like your view has no case for `POST`.

Comment: @IainShelvington added

Comment: @nadermx you should use a FormView not a TemplateView

Comment: @IainShelvington that worked, if you want to make the answer I will select it

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a `post` method in your `NewsletterView`:

```py
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
```

Check this out ;) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/#handling-forms-with-class-based-views